# java.lang.IllegalAccessError when making Spring Data repo package local

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data

I am trying to use packages by feature (As is done [here](https://github.com/olivergierke/whoops-architecture/tree/master/packages-after) for example). I created a `com.company.project.user` package with my `UserRepository` and `UserService` interfaces, making only the `UserService` public. I also have a subpackage `web` that has the `UserController` and a `UserDto`.

In this `web` package, I have a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
public class UserDtoTest {

    private JacksonTester<UserDto> tester;

    @Test
    public void testSerialize() throws IOException {
        String id = UUID.fromString("939d1c2f-b1f4-49c6-9839-f088401f6781").toString();
        String username = "wim.deblauwe";
        UserRole role = UserRole.ADMIN;
        JsonContent<UserDto> content = tester.write(new UserDto(id, username, role));
        assertThat(content).isEqualToJson("userdto.json");
    }
}
```

This uses Spring Boot 1.4.0.M3. This test runs fine when I run it alone or when I run it will all the tests in IntelliJ. However, when I run it from Maven (version 3.3.9), I get this problem:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
>   class com.company.project.user.$Proxy169 cannot access its
>   superinterface com.company.project.user.UserRepository

Bigger part of the stack trace:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class
>   com.company.project.user.$Proxy169 cannot access its
>   superinterface com.company.project.user.UserRepository    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     ... 59 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
>   class com.company.project.user.$Proxy169 cannot access its
>   superinterface com.company.project.user.UserRepository    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy.defineClass0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy.access$300(Proxy.java:228)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:642)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 71 common frames omitted

To make it work in Maven as well, I just have to change:

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UserId>, UserRepositoryCustom {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

to

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, UserId>, UserRepositoryCustom {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Any idea why I need to do this? Could it be a bug in Spring Data?

Comment: Are Spring Boot DevTools involved and the project is split up into multiple JARs?

Comment: I tried removing DevTools from my pom, but that does not help. There is only 1 JAR.

Comment: Hm, sounds like a bug to me but we're using package scoped repositories in a lot of samples, even with DevTools. Any chance you provide a tiny sample project so that we can play with it to find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6053). There are a couple of workarounds:

1. Mark any tests that use `WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` or `WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT` with `@DirtiesContext`.
2. Switch to Undertow or Jetty.